# Modal window CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

On this page, http://www.behance.net/signup, if you click "login", their modal window comes up.

I have already got a modal window in place, but cannot find which CSS they're using to style the border and everything within their modal window.

There's a lot of CSS and code there. How can I extract the styles for everything modal window related from there?

Comment: 1. Install Chrome, 2. Right click on the modal window and select 'Inspect Element' 3. Read through the applied CSS.

Answer (score 2):

default.css and fancybox.css

Learn how to use your browser's developer tools. In FF with Firebug or Chrome by default you can right click an element and choose inspect. This will show you a history of the css as well as what lines are contributing to each effect, the rules hierarchy and more.

Here is a youtube video on using the [Chrome developer tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI).

Answer (score 1):

It the class with id `site-left-column`. It seems to be on line 94 of **fancybox.css**. Learn to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) like tools from which you can easily figure out yourself.